# Migration from RC2 to 1.0 : Returning 'dynamic' from controller action causes strange web api response

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I recently migrated from RC2 to 1.0 and i have issues on web api response.

**For Action**

```
 public dynamic GetCountries(string startsWith)
        {
            return Ok(_countryService.GetList(startsWith));
        }
```

**Json Response In RC2**

```
[{
      "CountryCode": "ANG",
      "CountryName": "Angola"
    },
    {
      "CountryCode": "ANT",
      "CountryName": "Antigua and Barbuda"      
    }]
```

**Json Response in 1.0**

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "countryCode": "ANG",
      "countryName": "Angola"    
    },
    {
      "countryCode": "ANT",
      "countryName": "Antigua and Barbuda"
    }],
  "formatters": [],
  "contentTypes": [],
  "declaredType": null,
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

The response in 1.0 for dynamic type has added object wrapper which was not the case before with the properties being lower camel cased. 
Is there some thing i did wrong while migration?

**Project.json**

```
"dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens": "5.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",  
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },
```

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194

Comment: hmm, thanks. but thats for the camel case issue. Whats the issue with the additional wrapper in my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed a `bug` from aspnet team.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4960

Thanks [Kiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184056/kiran-challa) for pointing the issue link.

This has been stated as `done` but is not in current version `1.0` and only be available on `1.1.0`. However since `1.0.1` is not released yet, it **might** be available on `1.0.1` release.

Untill then using `IActionResult` is the only way.

`return Ok([dynamic object]);`

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4960

Why do you want the return type to be `dynamic` here? Why not return `IActionResult` instead?

Suggested workaround from the above issue or you could just change your return type to be `IActionResult`

```
public class Fix4960ActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var objectResult = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        if (objectResult?.Value is IActionResult)
        {
            context.Result = (IActionResult)objectResult.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using IActionResult does solve the issue. I guess i am just mad because I didn't find it in their migration document.

Comment: Usually known issues document has details of the issues that most users might usually hit. In this scenario returning object/dynamic is not a common pattern in my opinion.

Comment: actually this dynamic return type was used as default in previous version of web api.